# C - Public IP from file descriptor

Tags: c, sockets, ip

I have three process in three different computers.

Process 1, the client, asks Process 2 for the IP and PORT of Process 3.

Process 3 connected to Process 2 earlier, and Process 2 gets the IP of Process 3 from the file descriptor (Process 3 already knows the ip and port of Process 2).

This works fine, but if I try to run Process 2 and Process 3 in the same computer, the IP of Process 3 is always 127.0.0.1 so Process 1 never finds Process 3.

```
    socklen_t len;
    struct sockaddr_storage addr;
    char ipstr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

    len = sizeof addr;
    getpeername(fd, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, &len);

    struct sockaddr_in *s = (struct sockaddr_in *) &addr;

    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &s->sin_addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
```

This is the code I'm using, and **ipstr** is the IP I get.

How can I solve this?

Many thanks!

Comment: If the IP is 127.0.0.1, you process 2 could look up the address of the local machine's network interfaces. But there could be more than one, it will have to pick one to send to process 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If after the `getpeername()` call for process 3 socket you detect that the address is the localhost, you can instead call [`getsockname()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getsockname) for the process 1 socket to get the IP process 1 used to connect to process 2. So long as process 3 is listening to the same interfaces as process 2 when they are running on the same machine, process 1 should be able to connect to process 3 with the same address.

```
len = sizeof addr;
getpeername(p3_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, &len);
struct sockaddr_in *s = (struct sockaddr_in *) &addr;
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &s->sin_addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);

if (strcmp(ipstr, "127.0.0.1") == 0) {
    len = sizeof(addr);
    getsockname(p1_socket, (struct sockaddr *)addr, &len);
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &s->sin_addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
}
```

Comment: The fact that Process 3 is bound to 127.0.0.1 means that it is NOT bound to a network-accessible interface, so Process 1 would not be able to communicate with Process 3 directly at all.

Comment: It is more likely that process 3 is bound to INADDR_ANY but used localhost to connect to process 2.

Comment: That does not change what I said. The established connection would still be bound only to 127.0.0.1 once `connect()` is called, and thus would not be accessible to Process 1 over the network.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how process 2 connect process 3:

```
int connect (int sockfd,struct sockaddr * serv_addr,int addrlen);
```

if the *serv_addr* argument in *connect* function is localhost, so process *getpeername* will get localhost, if the *serv_addr* is the IP of the PC,so you can get the IP of the PC.

Answer (score 0):

If Process 3 is using 127.0.0.1, and Process 1 is on a different machine, then Process 1 would never be able to communicate with Process 3, as Process 3 would not have access to the network to begin with because 127.0.0.1 is isolated to just the local machine only.  Process 3 would have to be using the machine's actual network IP instead in order to be reachable by other machines on the network.